# Errors when installing Django 1.5 with Python 3

Tags: python, django, syntax, python-3.x, syntax-error

Django 1.5 should have experimental support for Python 3. After creating new virtualenv with Python and running `pip install django` I get a ton of syntax errors. The most interesting thing is that after that it says that Django was successfully installed. Anyway, when I try to start project with `django-admin.py`, it gives me syntax error and dies.

I'm using Arch Linux and this happens after activating virtualenv too.

**Edit**: Here is [the log](http://vpaste.net/Kazgp). It seems that it download Django 1.4 instead of 1.5.

**Edit #2**: Tried to explicitly set version to be 1.5 (`Django==1.5`), but it says it can't find it.

**Edit #3**: Of course I could simply grab the newest version from Git repo, but why it isn't in Pip repo if it's Django stable?

Comment: Is there a question here? Without showing the errors, its not really clear what you want help with.

Comment: It would help if you included the actual errors and log of the installation.

Comment: Plus, try cutting-edge master branch of Django for Py3.

Comment: Sure! I will update the question in second.

Comment: Added the log and comments about my actions.

Comment: I ran `pip install django` (from a virtualenv) earlier today and it sure did install 1.5. [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/1.5) shows 1.5 as well.

Comment: Strange because my system is surely up to date. Maybe I can somehow update Pip database cache (if there is such a thing)?

Comment: Try setting `use-mirrors=false` in `~/.pip/pip.conf` (if you don't have that file, `[global]<newline>use-mirrors=false`)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! [The content of it](http://vpaste.net/Hc1D0) before. P.S. Please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pip might be using an out-of-date mirror. You can stop pip from using mirrors by creating `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
use-mirrors=false
```